# How to place image next to simple text next to each other and in the center?

Tags: css, image, text, grid

I'd like to place this simple cat image next to some simple text, and I don't know how to do it.

I want them both to be next to each other in the middle of the page.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried in the past? Alot of people on this site won't even look to help you unless you have first tried to resolve your own issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin: 0 auto;` Or use `display:flex;justify-content: center;` to the parent tags of images and text.